Is it possible to have a background color AND background photo side-by-side using CSS?

Using a single outer wrapper container, is it possible to have a background color immediately next to a background photo as in the attached image? It needs to be a single wrapper, because I'd like to add a child div inside that will overlap this entire area. The photo needs to grow/shrink at the container grows/shrinks with the browser.
<div class="outerWrapper">
     <div class="innerWrapper"></div>
</div>


What did you try?

background can take image and a color. then you just move the image with background-position and set background-size to cover or contain and you have a starting point

"It needs to be a single wrapper, because I'd like to add a child div inside that will overlap this entire area." - why does it have to overlap the entire area? If the .innerWrapper here is supposed to provide the text content, then you will need to limit the width of that text somehow. So you should probably be able to limit the width of the inner wrapper instead to begin with, and then the wrapper could simply get the solid green background color ...

@CBroe - because ultimately this wrapper container needs to go edge to edge, but the content inside needs to stay within the defined width of the page content, which is about 1170px and centered in the page. I'll be able to restrict it further within there, but first I need a wrapper.

Yes. Backgrounds can be stacked/layered, sized and positioned. No layering is required to have a color with an image beside, just sizing and positioning.


.d1 {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url(http://picsum.photos/1000);
  background-size: 60% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
  padding: 0 calc(60% + 1em) 1em 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}
<div class="d1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>
</div>



After running this snippet, use the full page link to test the responsive behaviour.

This seems to work great, with one exception, the photo stretches out. Can cover be used here so that it scales instead?

cover won't work because it will then cover the whole container. You could try something like background-size: 50% auto;

If you want to use cover you need a separate element or pseudo-element. See the answer from @MDHasanPatwary.

Alternate solution using Flexbox to achieve a similar layout without relying heavily on background properties:


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 80vh;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}

.image {
  width: 60%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/1000" alt="background image">
  </div>
</div>



